# change nextAll() individually jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function func(x) {
  var y = $("#" + (x.id));
  //nextAll get the number at the end of their id -=1
  //y.nextAll().attr('id', )
  //
  y.remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="div1" onclick="func(this)">Lorem</div>
  <div id="div2" onclick="func(this)">Ipsum</div>
  <div id="div3" onclick="func(this)">Dolor</div>
  <div id="div4" onclick="func(this)">Sit</div>
  <div id="div5" onclick="func(this)">Amet</div>
</div>
```

How would I loop through every div after the selected div?
For example, if the user clicks on div2, div3 will have a function, along with div4 and div5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate the elements in the selection

```
function func(x) {
  var y = $(x);
  y.nextAll().each(function(index, element){
    // do something 
  })

  y.remove()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To catch only the divs after the clicked element:

```js
function func(x) {
  $(x).nextAll().remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="div1" onclick="func(this)">Lorem</div>
  <div id="div2" onclick="func(this)">Ipsum</div>
  <div id="div3" onclick="func(this)">Dolor</div>
  <div id="div4" onclick="func(this)">Sit</div>
  <div id="div5" onclick="func(this)">Amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using **[Next Siblings Selector (“target selector ~ next siblings selector”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)**

```js
$('[id^=div]').on('click', function() {
  $(`#${$(this).attr('id')} ~ div`).fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove()
  });
});
```

```css
[id^=div] {
  border: 1px dashed lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="div1">Lorem</div>
  <div id="div2">Ipsum</div>
  <div id="div3">Dolor</div>
  <div id="div4">Sit</div>
  <div id="div5">Amet</div>
</div>
```